# Record is not getting inserted in session table in rails applications

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I developed an application in rails framework. I used session table to store session using `config.action_controller.session_store = active_record_store` in config file. Everything was running fine. I redeployed this application on other server, but session table is there but on each login it is not creating any entry in sessions table. (`Ruby 1.8.7` and `Rails 3.2.12`) Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: are you using devise? Was it strong to your DB when you ran it in your local DB? Did u run the migration for the active record store?

Comment: Yes.. migrations run successfully, tables got created. M not using devise. Is ther any cookie setting on server that is destroying session or somethign like that?